# Light fixture in bedroom closet?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

Does current electric code mandate an installation of a light fixture in every bedroom's closet?

Comment: What country/state/etc.? (Codes vary around the world). I suspect the answer is dependent on the size of the closet - a 2' x 4' closet is very different from a 6' x 8' walk-in closet.

Comment: California, 2' x 4' closet, residential.

Comment: I think it is. But way back when,If closet was 3x3  or larger you put in light over door. Kept Ahj happy and  did not have to  worry about  shelf , clearances.

Comment: Ya 2x4 was funny If room had a light boss didnt add closet light, If it only had switched outlets  for lights he would put in a closet light .

Comment: The answer is yes .Not sure what your asking. there are rules on ,what type of light to were it can be installed in the closet'